# Bytes taken by a set of innoDB rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, innodb

I am wondering whether there's a way to measure the number of bytes a certain number of rows occupy on the disk, considering the fact that some of the columns are varchars.

Many thanks,

Vlad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To measure the number of bytes occupied by rows on the disk, you must know how much disk space is required for each data type.

**Documentation:**
[Data Type Storage Requirements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/storage-requirements.html)
[The CHAR and VARCHAR Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/char.html)

**Example:**
A table is made of 2 fields (a BIGINT field and a VARCHAR(400) field).
The BIGINT field will always use 8 bytes. The VARCHAR field uses 2 bytes + the number of characters actually stored.
So, if one record stores 300 characters, the total number of bytes used by this record will be: 8+2+300 = 310 bytes

> In contrast to CHAR, VARCHAR values are stored as a 1-byte or 2-byte
>   length prefix plus data. The length prefix indicates the number of
>   bytes in the value. A column uses one length byte if values require no
>   more than 255 bytes, two length bytes if values may require more than
>   255 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

It may be useful to read [The physical structure of records in InnoDB](http://blog.jcole.us/2013/01/10/the-physical-structure-of-records-in-innodb/) and the other articles in my [InnoDB](http://blog.jcole.us/innodb/) series. If you provided your table schema (from `SHOW CREATE TABLE`) I'd also be happy to work through it as an example. Unfortunately there is really no way to measure the physical row size built into MySQL.